# how to delete duplicate records from array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have this object in Javascript.

```
[{"col1": 1, "col2": 25},{"col1": 1, "col2": 25},{"col1": 3, "col2": 30}]
```

How can I drop duplicate records in order to get this result?

```
[{"col1": 1, "col2": 25},{"col1": 3, "col2": 30}]
```

I have tried next logic, but does not work:

```
[...new Set(myData)]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218999/remove-duplicates-from-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently read this on another answer and I liked it, this uses the optional argument of `filter()` that is passed as `this` inside the filter function.

```js
const input = [
    {"col1": 1, "col2": 25},
    {"col1": 1, "col2": 25},
    {"col1": 3, "col2": 30}
];

let res = input.filter(function({col1, col2})
{
    return !this.has(`${col1}-${col2}`) && this.add(`${col1}-${col2}`)
}, new Set());

console.log(res);
```

Comment: That's a nice way to use the second argument of `fitler()`.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const a = [{"col1": 1, "col2": 25},{"col1": 1, "col2": 25},{"col1": 3, "col2": 30}];

console.log(
  a.reduce(
    (acc, val) => !acc.some(({col1, col2}) => val.col1 === col1 && val.col2 === col2) 
                  ? acc.concat(val) 
                  : acc, 
     []
  )
);
```

Comment: This would be the first option on my mind, so +1 for you!

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52202049/10221765) shows a simple `filter` operation with a `Set`:

```js
const data = [{"col1": 1, "col2": 25},{"col1": 1, "col2": 25},{"col1": 3, "col2": 30}];

const unique = data.filter(function({ col1, col2 }) { return !this.has(`${col1}-${col2}`) && this.add(`${col1}-${col2}`)}, new Set);

console.log(unique);
```

Comment: And just hope you don't have data like: `{"col1": 12, "col2": 3},{"col1": 1, "col2": 23},`?

Comment: Fixed @MarkMeyer